# Why pressing the left arrow key in MonoDevelop's code editor panel changes the panel focus instead of moving the cursor?

Tags: gnome, mono, monodevelop

That behavior is so wrong. The arrow keys should move the cursor, not the panel focus.
How to fix it?

Comment: Turned me off MonoDevelop so fast.

Comment: I don't remember having this issue in monodevelop, but I will verify.

Comment: I just checked, and I don't see this occurring on my system :)

Comment: @Roland I changed the title to emphasize that I'm talking about the keyboard, not the mouse

Comment: I am talking about the keyboard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable IBUS.

This is mostly the cause for such breaks - it's a known bug in the IBUS daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Disable iBUS - confirming Mike Krüger's answer.

You can turn off iBUS per page, by right clicking anywhere on an open page (in Monodevelop), right-click > input methods > None.

I haven't had this issue since I updated to Ubuntu 11.04, but I had it in 10.10. There were a few months where I didn't use Monodevelop so maybe an update during that time fixed it?